# MongoDB querying Gmail data

Tags: mongodb, gmail, nosql

I enabled the Google Gmail API and I am having trouble with MongoDB queries (first time doing them). I want to get the count of the emails where the message body size is greater than 100.

I have this:

```
db.gmail_data.aggregate(
    [
        { $match: { 'payloads.parts.body.size': { $gt: 100 } }},
        { $group: { _id: null, count: { $sum: 1 }}}
    ]
);
```

I end up getting this message: `Failed to call method", "code" : 1`. Sorry if simple mistake, I'm completely new to NoSQL. The data in the document looks like this:

```
{
    _id:"AAA",
    snippet:"",
    historyId:"AAA",
    labelIds:[
        "IMPORTANT",
        "SENT",
        "INBOX"
    ],
    threadId:"AAA",
    sizeEstimate:24281,
    id:"AAA",
    internalDate:"123123213",
    payload:{
        mimeType:"multipart/mixed",
        filename:"",
        headers:[
            {
                name:"Return-Path",
                value:"<email@gmail.com>"
            },
            {
                name:"Received",
                value:"from [ip_here] (metadata)"
            },
            {
                name:"To",
                value:"email@gmail.com"
            },
            {
                name:"From",
                value:"Byron <email@gmail.com>"
            },
            {
                name:"Subject",
                value:"Some subject"
            },
            {
                name:"Message-ID",
                value:"<message_id@gmail.com>"
            },
            {
                name:"Date",
                value:"Fri, 12 Nov 2011 05:17:54 -0200"
            },
            {
                name:"User-Agent",
                value:"Some user-agen"
            },
            {
                name:"MIME-Version",
                value:"1.0"
            },
            {
                name:"Content-Type",
                value:"Some content-type"
            }
        ],
        parts:[
            {
                mimeType:"text/plain",
                filename:"",
                headers:[
                    {
                        name:"Content-Type",
                        value:"text/plain; charset=utf-8; format=flowed"
                    },
                    {
                        name:"Content-Transfer-Encoding",
                        value:"7bit"
                    }
                ],
                partId:"0",
                body:{
                    data:"453",
                    size:2
                }
            },
            {
                mimeType:"text/plain",
                filename:"file.zip",
                headers:[
                    {
                        name:"Content-Type",
                        value:"text/plain; charset=UTF-8; name="file.zip""
                    },
                    {
                        name:"Content-Transfer-Encoding",
                        value:"base64"
                    },
                    {
                        name:"Content-Disposition",
                        value:"attachment; filename="file.zip""
                    }
                ],
                partId:"1",
                body:{
                    size:14219,
                    attachmentId:"AAB"
                }
            },
            {
                mimeType:"text/plain",
                filename:"file2.zip",
                headers:[
                    {
                        name:"Content-Type",
                        value:"text/plain; charset=UTF-8; name="file2.zip""
                    },
                    {
                        name:"Content-Transfer-Encoding",
                        value:"base64"
                    },
                    {
                        name:"Content-Disposition",
                        value:"attachment; filename="file2.zip""
                    }
                ],
                partId:"2",
                body:{
                    size:2503,
                    attachmentId:"AAC"
                }
            }
        ],
        body:{
            size:0
        }
    }
}
```

How do I get the information in each place inside the JSON? I tried looking at the documentation on MongoDB's website and came up with that query above, but I can't figure out what's wrong.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: are you sure you have the right document ? the query has "payloads" and the docment has "payload".

Comment: Thank you very much! Can't believe I missed that.

Comment: was that it ? I'm not sure the query you've gets what you need. Add the expected response if you need answer.